# HTTP Post data object not complete when received by backend

Tags: angularjs, node.js, nodemailer

I am trying to send an email using a contact form in AngularJS, the server side is programmed in NodeJS, to send the email by smtp I am using the nodemailer library, the AngularJS side the form is sending the data, but the server side not received this data, only show me an object named IncomingMessage with many items, but I don't see my email data.

Angular side

```
angular.module('contactApp', [])
.factory('postEmailForm',['$http',function($http){

return {

 postEmail: function(emailData,callback){
    console.log(emailData);
   $http.post("/contact-form", emailData).success(callback);
     }
   }
}])

.controller('ContactController', function ($scope,postEmailForm) {

$scope.sendMail = function () {
console.log("Entro!");
var req = {
 headers: {
   'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-     Type, Accept'
 },
 data:
  {
    contactName : this.contactName,
    contactEmail : this.contactEmail,
    contactMsg : this.contactMsg
  }
}

  postEmailForm.postEmail(req, function (res) {
      console.log(req);
    if (res.type == false) {
      //do something
    }else{

      console.log("OK");
    }

  })

 };

});
```

Server side

```
var express=require('express');
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
var app = express();
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
var http = require('http');
app.use(serveStatic("."));
app.get('/',function(req,res){
res.sendfile('index.html');
 }); 

  var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP",{
   service: "Gmail",
  auth: {
  user: "sending email",
  pass: "sending pass"
  }
  });

 app.post('/contact-form',function(req,res){
 //Your NodeMailer logic comes here
 console.log(req.data);

 var mailOptions={
 from : req.data.contactEmail,
 to: recipient email
 subject : "Contact",
 text : req.data.contactMsg
 }
  console.log(mailOptions);
  smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response){
  if(error){
  console.log('Server error ' + error);
  res.end("error");
 }else{
 console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
  res.end("sent");
  }
});
```

Comment: Have you checked the data object at POST time?

Comment: Yes, I make debugging and I am sending the object to endpoint, but the object req is not received.

Comment: Have you tested your POST API on postman yet?

Comment: Yes, I found the solution I forgot use body-parse in my server file to read the response req.body

Comment: You can answer your own question, and then accept that as the answer...

Answer (score 0):

I forgot add body-parser on the server side, to parse the data

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```